# Convert address to a string in solidity

Tags: solidity

```
Strings.toHexString(uint160(address), 20)
```

Converts address to hexadecimal which is not checkedsum.
Is there a standard way to do it and keep the checkedsum property?

Comment: Why do you need it in solidity? Most frameworks do it off-chain, which is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Well no, it's just a number you're converting to an hex string. You'd have to compute the checksum, i guess. Also, may i ask why in the world would you want to convert an address to a string in solidity instead of doing it in another language?

Comment: I'm trying to create a "address+number" string to use it to verify if it is one of the leaf in a merkle tree. How can I do the conversion and keep the checkedsum address?

Comment: That doesnt answer my question, why do you want to create that "address+number" string in solidity instead of creating it off chain and just  passing it to your contract?